# Keycloak accepts email without domain name for user registration

Tags: java, validation, email, keycloak

Is there any setting i have to make for Keycloak to deny emails like "email@withoutdomain" (no dot)?
I tried some but it looks like it is still accepting these type of emails. I need to make sure it is respecting an RFC regarding email addresses.
Thanks!